# Ao compartilhar o link pelo app não carrega nem foto nem texto na versão do iPhone. No Android funciona perfeito

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, plugin

Olá, tenho um app desenvolvido em Flutter. Nele tem uma lista de noticias que o usuário pode compartilhar. Estou usando o plugin share do Dart packages. No android o compartilhamento está funcionando perfeitamente, eu passo o link do item na web e o android carrega a foto e o título e forma o conjunto. Já no iPhone não está funcionando. Na verdade ele compartilha, mas não carrega nem o título, nem a foto. Alguém pode me dar uma luz de onde estou errando? Abaixo vou postar o código da página com a lista de noticias e a implementação do compartilhamento no método _shareLink(String texto).

O resultado do código no Android e no iPhone estão nas imagens abaixo:

No Android:
[image: Resultado no Android]

No iPhone:
[image: Resultado no Iphone]

```
import 'package:alba_app/helpers/noticia_helper.dart';
import 'package:alba_app/models/noticia_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:share/share.dart';

class PlaceNoticiaWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  PlaceNoticiaWidget();

  @override
  PlaceNoticiaWidgetState createState() => PlaceNoticiaWidgetState();
}

class PlaceNoticiaWidgetState extends State<PlaceNoticiaWidget> {
  NoticiaHelper helperNoti = NoticiaHelper();
  NoticiaModel noti = NoticiaModel();
  List<NoticiaModel> listNotis = List();
  String path;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    helperNoti.getAllNoticias().then((list) {
      setState(() {
        listNotis = list;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: listaNoticias(),
    );
  }

  listaNoticias() {
    return ListView.separated(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, top: 5.0, right: 0.0, bottom: 5.0),
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(color: Colors.black54),
        itemCount: listNotis.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(
              listNotis[index].dataNoticia,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black87),
            ),
            subtitle: Text(
              listNotis[index].titleNoticia,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              maxLines: 2,
            ),
            leading: Image.network(
              listNotis[index].fotoNoticia,
            ),
            onTap: () {
              showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                    title: Text("Qual o seu desejo?"),
                    content: Text(
                      listNotis[index].titleNoticia,
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(
                        onPressed: (){
                          _launchURL(listNotis[index].linkNoticia);
                          Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                        },
                        child: Text("Ler a íntegra da noticia!"),
                      ),
                      FlatButton(
                        onPressed: (){
                          _shareLink(listNotis[index].linkNoticia);
                          Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                        },
                        child: Text("Compartilhar"),
                      ),
                      FlatButton(
                          onPressed: (){
                            Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                          },

                          child: Text('FECHAR'))
                    ],
                  ));
            },
          );
        });
  }

  _launchURL(String urlNew) async {

    var url = urlNew;
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }

  _shareLink(String texto) async {
    await Share.share(texto);
  }

}
```

Hoje consegui um aparelho físico para rodar o aplicativo. Debugando apareceu um erro, quando acionada a função de compartilhamento. Abaixo posto o erro que aparece no console.

========

```
WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: { 
     filterBlacklist = ();
     filterWhitelist = ();
     restrictWeb = 1;
     useContentFilter = 0;
     useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
     whitelistEnabled = 0;
  }
WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
```

Alguém pode me dar uma luz sobre como resolver esse problema?

Comment: Como é um problema específico iOS fica mais difícil de ajudar, porém você pode adicionar imagens dos dois sistema para detalhar melhor o problema.

Comment: @rubStackOverflow, Postei a imagem com o resultado da ação share nos dois aplicativos. O que eu quero saber é se estou deixando passar alguma configuração específica do iPhone, na utilização do plugin.